# Changing the background image when clicking on the div?

Tags: javascript, html

I am creating a table with div's that already have a background image in them. The classes are "sw", "sl", "so", "sa", "sn", and "su". I made that you could click on the div's and to the right will show the information for that div.

However, I tried adding a hover element to these div's, which work when I do not add the onclick function. With the onclick function, there is no hover that changes the div into a different background image. The background image stays the same when I click on a certain div.

How can you make the background image change when you click on the div?

Here is my HTML code:

```
<table width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
    <tr>
        <td><div class="sw" onclick="show(0)"></div></td>
        <td><div class="sl" onclick="show(1)"></div></td>
        <td id="info" rowspan="3" style="width:325px;"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><div class="so" onclick="show(2)"></div></td>
        <td><div class="sa" onclick="show(3)"></div></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><div class="sn" onclick="show(4)"></div></td>
        <td><div class="su" onclick="show(5)"></div></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

And here is my JavaScript code:

```
function show(num) {
    var outputInfo = "";
    if(num == 0) {
        outputInfo += 'INFO HERE';
    }
    else if(num == 1) {
        outputInfo += 'INFO HERE';
    }
    ...
    document.getElementById("info").innerHTML = outputInfo;
}
```

Oh, and by the way, my background images are used on the CSS portion and all of the classes above share the same image but they were assigned different positions.

Is there a way to show the images as separate backgrounds if another approach to clicking on a div?

Comment: Where is your hover element and onclick event that demonstrates your problem?

Comment: Please go read [ask], and how to create a [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using onclick, maybe try using something Tomm did. I probably encourage you to create a class for all of these id elements. Since you had a shared background image for the original background before the function is clicked, I added background-position. Here is what I did for the script by making a function that I put in the onload of the body (first portion is for backgrounds when clicked, second portion is for original background and will only show for those that are not clicked):

```
function onloadPage() {
    // first portion
    $('#sw').click(function() {
        $(this).css("background-position", "0 0");
        document.getElementById("info").innerHTML = 'INFO HERE';
    });
    $('#sl').click(function() {
        $(this).css("background-position", "0 0");
        document.getElementById("info").innerHTML = 'INFO HERE';
    });
    ...

    // second portion
    $('.classname').on('click', function(e) {
        if(!$(e.target).closest('#sw').length) { $('#sw').css("background-position", '0 0'); }
        if(!$(e.target).closest('#sl').length) { $('#sl').css("background-position", '0 0'); }
        ...
}
```

And then the HTML:

```
<table width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
    <tr>
        <td><div class="classname" id="sw" style="background-position:0 0;"></div></td>
        <td><div class="classname" id="sl"></div></td>
        <td id="classinfo" rowspan="3" style="width:325px;"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Obviously you will have to adjust your background-positions to the way you need it to look.

Comment: Hey this seems to be working well for me, I just have some little problems. And thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a simple onclick function in javascript/jQuery ( I use this code with jQuery 1.7.1 ) like the following:

```
$('#changeMe').on('click', function() {
    $('#changeMe').css('background-image', 'url(urlhere)');
})
```

*Where* `#changeMe` *is the div id*

```js
$('#changeMe').on('click', function() {
    $('#changeMe').css('background-image', 'url(http://firefoxzeneize.altervista.org/FirefoxLogo.png)');
})
```

```css
div{
    width : 512px;
    height : 512px;
    background-image : url("https://www.notebookcheck.net/fileadmin/Notebooks/News/_nc3/20170911_Google_Chrome_logo_vector_download.png");

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div id="changeMe"></div>
```

Comment: This does not really answer the question, plus it is not even correct (this is jQuery code, so you can _not_ “make this in javascript” alone like that.)

Comment: @CBroe i forgot to mention that this is using jQuery 1.7.1

Comment: I am not sure if I quite get this but I will try.

Comment: @JJY i added a snippet so you can see how it works if you still do not understand it

Answer (score 0):

Well, your code should looks like:

```
document.getElementById("info").style.backgroundImage = "url('image.png')";
```

here I am assuming that `info` is the id of the div which you want to change background.

Comment: No, the info is not the div I wanted to change the background with, but thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

This snippet should do. I've linked a couple of random images so you can test it. 
By clicking on the div, the info is displayed on the right and that div's background gets updated. By passing the 'this' keyword as argument of the show method you can avoid logics that depend on the div's id.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Page Title</title>
</head>
<body>
<style>
.sw{
background-image: url("https://mdn.mozillademos.org/files/6457/mdn_logo_only_color.png");
}
.sl{
background-image: url("https://mdn.mozillademos.org/files/7693/catfront.png");
}
</style>
<script>
function show(num, t) {
    var outputInfo = "";
    if(num == 0) {
        outputInfo += 'This is the information about the image now displayed in div0';
        var newUrl='url("http://www.librosweb.es/website/css/images/logo.gif")';
        t.style.backgroundImage= newUrl; 
    }
    else if(num == 1) {
        outputInfo += 'This is the information about the image now displayed in div1' ;
        var newUrl='url("http://www.librosweb.es/website/css/images/logo.gif")';
        t.style.backgroundImage= newUrl; 
    }
    document.getElementById("info").innerHTML = outputInfo;
}
</script>

<table width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" >
    <tr>
        <td style="border: 1px solid red"><div class="sw" onclick="show(0, this)"></div></td>
        <td style="border: 1px solid red"><div class="sl" onclick="show(1, this)"></div></td>
        <td style="border: 1px solid red" id="info" rowspan="3" style="width:325px;"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you for the help but it did not work for me...I could not see any image and it was just a white screen.

Comment: sorry, my bad. You can't actually see nothing because divs resize themselves to fit their content. Since they don't have content, you don't see the divs. So, to test the above snippet, add some text in the div with class sw and in the div in the class sl. Like this.  <td style="border: 1px solid red"><div class="sw" onclick="show(0, this)">aaaaaaaaaaaa</div></td>
        <td style="border: 1px solid red"><div class="sl" onclick="show(1, this)">bbbbbbbbbbb</div></td>